# How do you send Image data to a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf-binding

I've searched and tried all previous posted suggested solutions and have not had any luck. I am obviously doing something wrong which I just can't figure out and I'm hoping someone will be able to help me here.My problem is this:

I have a WCF Service, and a WCF client. When I call the service and try to pass a byte array (uploading an image to the service), I get a Target Invokation exception error which is very vague. So, I hooked up tracing and the trace log is telling me the message quota size exceeded the limit, but I have modified the configs on both ends (app.config & web.config) to contain a really large limit. The problem is, it's telling me that the limit of 65536 was exceeded, but as you can see from my configs below it's way larger than that amount, so it's as if my client is using some other configuration values or I just didn't configure it right and it's ignoring what I have. Can someone help me?

App.Config:
[image]

Web.Config:
[image]

Any help you guys could offer would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this problem now for two days.

Thanks everyone.

Here's the actual configuration code:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>            
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDataSyncService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/DataSyncWCF/DataSyncService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDataSyncService"
            contract="IDataSyncService" name="WSHttpBinding_IDataSyncService">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Web.Config:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DataSyncWCF.Service1Behavior"
    name="DataSyncWCF.DataSyncService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingName="WSHttpBinding_IDataSyncService"
      contract="DataSyncWCF.IDataSyncService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>      
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DataSyncWCF.Service1Binding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">            
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DataSyncWCF.Service1Behavior">          
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Here's my code calling the WCF Service:

```
VehicleImage vi = new VehicleImage();
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\images\1FAHP35N18W1589_01.jpg",        System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
int len = (int)fs.Length;
vi = new VehicleImage();
vi.Image = new Byte[len];            
fs.Read(vi.Image, 0, len);   

// Here's the call to the WCF Service. It never makes it to the Service because of the message size limit error.
ResponseContract rc = client.SyncImage(vi);
```

Comment: Did you try restarting the server after changing the config file? Also, have you tried sending an image smaller than 65K? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: Tip: Post code, XML too, as text with the proper formatting ( `{}` button). Makes searching etc a lot easier.

Comment: @Paul Sasik I did try sending a smaller image that was less than 65k and that does work. The problem is, I'm going to be sending image sizes around 90 - 120K each.

Answer (score 4):

Everything in WCF is heavily limited (throttled), with reason.

I see a lot of 2G numbers in your config, that would not be a good idea in general. And you may have missed a few,  I can't spot a SerializationLimit (approx name) so quickly.

There are 2 basic ways to deal with large messages in WCF: [MTOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) and streaming.

Comment: Yes, I only put the values up so high because of the error that I'm receiving. I increased the number to such a high value to see if that would fix the issue and then I would work my way backwards to decrease it after knowing that I had a resolution. I have already tried MTOM and that didn't change the result either.

Comment: I would consider a Stream. Easy to work with and it surfaces the streaming (async) behaviour that is need anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config wsHttpBinding, set the `maxReceivedMessageSize`:

```
<binding name="www" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
```

Comment: Yes, I have set that value in both the client config and the web.config.

Comment: Can you add the exact error message that you are receiving? This will help us pinpoint the configuration that needs to be changed (fyi: we are successfully transferring very large (>1GB) files over WCF, so there isn't an inherent issue).